# Java / Groovy Socket - Detecting the socket being closed in a non-blocking way

Tags: java, groovy, input, sockets, nonblocking

I'm trying to create a small HTTP proxy that can re-write the request/headers as needed to suit my requirements.  If one already exists, please, point me to it.  Otherwise...

I've written something that ALMOST works.  It can do the proxy function, but not the re-write (yet).  Problem is, I can't detect when the remote socket has been closed down without doing a blocking read.  It is CRITICAL for the functionality of this thing that it be able to detect the socket being closed without blocking.  I have SCOURED the Java API documentation, and I can't find ANY indication that it is even possible.  Here's what I have:

```
    while ( this.inbound.isConnected() && this.outbound.isConnected() ) { 

      try {
        while ( ( available = readFromClient.available() ) != 0 ) { 
          if ( available > 1024 ) available = 1024
          bytesRead = readFromClient.read( buffer, 0, available )
          writeToServer.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead )
        }   

        while ( ( available = readFromServer.available() ) != 0 ) { 
          if ( available > 1024 ) available = 1024
          bytesRead = readFromServer.read( buffer, 0, available )
          writeToClient.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead )
        }                                                                                       
      } catch (e) { 
        print e
      }   

      println "Connected:      " + this.inbound.isConnected() 
      println "Bound:          " + this.inbound.isBound() 
      println "InputShutdown:  " + this.inbound.isInputShutdown() 
      println "OutputShutdown: " + this.inbound.isOutputShutdown() 
      print "\n";

      Thread.sleep( 10 )

    }
```

The tests for the socket being closed never indicate that the socket was closed.  And, as I mentioned, I can't find ANY examples of how to detect the 'END OF FILE' condition on the stream without doing a blocking read.

There HAS to be a way.  Does anyone here know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using `java.net.Socket` for your I/O.  In order to do non-blocking I/O in Java, you have to use the NIO package.

In particular, you'll want to use a `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` for communication.  Call `configureBlocking(false)` on the channel, then read() will either return the amount of data read, -1 for closed, or zero if no data is available.  An exception could be thrown on some error conditions as well.

Here's an [example](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/example/Ping.java) showing non-blocking I/O using a SocketChannel.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't help.  How can you even know that you're supposed to read if the connection is shut-down on the other side, and the java nio selector doesn't put the channel in the ready set when this happens?

It's just broken by design so far as I can tell, and there's no way to do this.  Please someone correct me if I'm mistaken...

Comment: Agreed!  I am facing this problem at the moment - if the other side is killed I don't receive a read event and even a write to the socket don't error.  What a pain...